# Mac OS X free C compiler

Tags: c++, c, macos, compiler-construction

Is there a small, free C or C++ compiler for OS X, like TCC?

Xcode is not small, or simple like TCC, AFAIK.

I'm looking for something like a GCC binary file or TCC for OS X.

Comment: GCC has already been mentioned, so I'm not sure why you're still looking for it.

Comment: He seems to want a binary of `gcc` so that he doesn't have to install Xcode. I don't think there's precompiled version of either `tcc` or `gcc` for a Mac, so it's a Catch 22. You need a compiler to compile your small compiler. So you probably need Xcode first (as it comes with `gcc`.)

Comment: There's XCode, or there are binaries available via fink or macports, but both of those require you to download and install a crapload too, so... really, you're best off not poluting your setup and just grab XCode.

Comment: @Matthew - Actually you can't install Fink or MacPorts unless you _already_ have Xcode. So, even if you could get a binary from one of them afterwards, you still need Xcode first. Beyond that the current version of Xcode is a 995MB download; MacPorts is 415K, and Fink is 14MB. So it's weird to complain about MacPorts and Fink requiring a 'crapload' of anything. Mac should provide a way to get a binary of `gcc` _without_ the damn IDE. Still, if you buy a Mac, you should know what you're getting: their way or the highway.

Comment: Small correction: there is a Fink binary that you can install without Xcode. However, as far as I can tell, there is no binary version of `gcc` that you can install _without_ some version of Xcode installed. (There is a binary of `gcc` 4.2, but it depends on Xcode directly as well as on libraries and other packages that are only available in source form.)

Comment: MacPorts and Fink are small as far as the executables themselves go, but to install anything, they require their own builds of everything that something depends on. That is what I was refering to.

Answer (score 31):

[gcc](http://developer.apple.com/technology/xcode.html) is the most widely used one (and Apple provides official builds of it as part of XCode). XCode is also usually distributed on your OS X cd's, though that version may be a little out of date now, depending on what version of OS X you have.

[For information and samples on how to use it, look here.](http://developer.apple.com/tools/gcc_overview.html)

Look into [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) or one of the [similar projects](http://www.macports.org/) out there if you want a build of gcc that's not linked to Xcode. That said though, Xcode is a great IDE for OS X.

Comment: If you install XCode, you can then use gcc directly from the command line if you want...

Comment: "Programs must be compiled to run in a standard Windows XP/Vista environment. This is the environment we will use to test your programs" - from my Data Structure assignment. Have to code in C++. If I do it in Mac will I have problem?

Comment: @Richa: Yes, most likely. If it's just Data Structure stuff, then you can probably get away with cross compiling, but you will still need to test it still works under Windows before submitting your assignments.

Comment: Okay Thanks! so what best do you suggest? I will be having lot of assignment from now on all with the same advice. This is just the first one.

Comment: @Richa: I used to use Parallels on my old Macbook and it works great. Go pick up a copy of Parallels, a basic copy of Windows and download a C++ compiler for that. `gcc` works on Windows too, or Visual Studio is another popular solution (there is a free edition available).

Comment: @Matthew Sorry for troubling again. Just want to confirm. I created a new command line tool application under MacOSX. The C++ program is running under it. Will the same program work in windows, since the command line tool is under MacOSX? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Richa: At the very least, you'll need to recompile it under Windows. Windows and MacOS use two different executable formats. You may get lucky and it might just work under Windows, depending on what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Xcode Tools that are already included in OSX.

> [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/Tools/) is the same professional
>   developer toolset used by Apple to
>   create Mac OS X, as well as many great
>   Apple applications, and Xcode is
>   included with every copy of Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Code::Blocks IDE](http://www.codeblocks.org/) its simple slick and hav good set of feture, a plus opensurce and ready to dl for 3 major plateforms

still recoment using Xcode if u just have to make projects for MAC, but if u are going to port it to linux and windows, then my choice is Code::Blocks [Give it a try atleast]

Answer (score 3):

I know you want a small compiler, but it is best to just download and install Xcode. It is a great IDE. From there, **you don't have to use it if you don't want to**. Once it is installed, you can use something like this in terminal:

```
gcc myFile.c -o myFile
```

And that would build a source file called myFile.c which contains C code and the output module (executable) would be `myFile`. You'd execute it by running:

```
./myFile
```

**Update**: What is your reason for not wanting Xcode? Furthermore, is **[GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)** itself ok (disregarding Xcode for a moment)?  It's important to know that GCC is not a part of Xcode. Apple made use of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), which is an open source C/C++ (and more) compiler.

I just can't find binaries of GCC for mac so downloading Xcode is an easy way to get some...

**Update 2**: It also just came to my attention that NetBeans will compile C / C++ Code. It also uses the [GCC compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/). I'm not sure if it using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) from my Xcode installation but I thought I'd mention this.

Best Regards,
Frank

Comment: Encouragement is not preaching. He didn't post a reason for not using Xcode. Furthermore, I'm suggesting Xcode to get GCC and then showing how to USE gcc to compile. GCC is NOT Xcode. Xcode USES GCC.

Comment: I've been using Xcode for a while. It's nice, but I don't know that I'd call it a "great" IDE. It has some funkiness to it. Good point that Xcode gives you gcc, but Xcode seems like a lot to grab just to get gcc. Maybe it's the safest way to get gcc, though. Apple will always make sure that there's a solid gcc installed.

Comment: More importantly, if you want to develop for OS X, sooner or later you'll have to write some Objective-C code, and that will have to be compiled by the Apple GCC. The only easy way to get a working installation of Apple's GCC is to install XCode, even if you later delete the IDE itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are binary packages for [LLVM](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html), both for the Clang and GCC front-ends.

Answer (score 1):

[PCC, the Portable C Compiler](http://pcc.ludd.ltu.se/), is available for the Mac. It is small and free. Its tarball weighs in at total of 1778 KB from its 4th of July CVS Snapshot.

Comment: I don't see a Mac binary for PCC on that page; am I missing it? If there isn't one, we are back to the Catch 22: the OP first has to install Xcode and gcc in order to compile a smaller compiler.

Comment: Yeah, you have to compile it with gcc.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use Xcode install the macports from [macports.org](http://www.macports.org/) and if you like a graphical user interface install [porticus](http://porticus.alittledrop.com/) as a managment gui for all the installed ports. In Porticus you can now easily install all different versions of gcc without Xcode. 
Porticus will compile the packages for your mac and install all the needed dependencies like a Linux packet manager.

Comment: You can't install MacPorts unless you have installed Xcode. So Porticus is not really an alternative to Xcode.

Comment: Yes you are right :) MacPorts depends on the Xcode compiler even if you install another version of gcc it will be compiled with the Xcode compiler. My fault